# Erro ao remover tabela no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando instalar e configurar o PostgreSQL na minha máquina, porém estou tendo algumas dúvidas e alguns problemas.

Segui os seguintes passos do tutorial de instalação no [site oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).
Estou utilizando o Linux Mint cinnamon 18.2.

[Aqui](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d3d007520bb2a8ebfb0171b176a813c0) estão as configurações da minha máquina.

---

Após a instalação, segui [este](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps) tutorial.

O primeiro problema surgiu ao digitar o comando
`su - postgres`, pois me foi pedido uma senha, que não era a senha do meu usuário atual e eu não faço ideia de qual senha seja essa.
Procurei por soluções na internet e vi [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765367/6039697) resposta, então tentei o comando `sudo su - postgres`, inseri a minha senha e consegui trocar de usuário.

Consegui executar todos os próximos comandos exceto o último (`DROP TABLE test.test;`), o qual resultou no seguinte erro `ERROR:  must be owner of relation test`

Também achei estranho o fato de que mesmo após executar os comandos para fornecer os privilégios ao meu usuário recém criado, após executar o comando `\du` a lista de privilégios do meu usuário continuou vazia.

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 michael   |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON postgres.* TO michael@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '<senha>';
syntax error at or near "TO"

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando **su** em bash é utilizado para elevar como super usúario  (**root**) e manter o usuário como administrador após a execução do comando. Já o comando **sudo** em bash roda o comando como administrador em seguida retorna para o usuário atual. Só é necessário a utilização de um desses dois comandos. Portanto a senha solicitada era do usúario root do sistema.

Sobre Permissões e usúarios :

Parece que você criou o usúario **michael** mas não vinculou permissões ao banco de dados, rode um GRANT All, deve corrigir o seu problema :

**Sintaxe em mysql :**

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO michael@localhost IDENTIFIED BY
>   'sua_senha';

**Sintaxe em PostgreeSQL :**

> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO
>   user_name;

veja exemplos da sintaxe nesta url também:

[PostgreeSQL Sintaxe Grant All](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user)

Comment: E porque que quando eu digito o comando `su` e insiro minha senha aparece `su: Authentication failure`? O super usuário já vem com uma senha default?

Comment: O super usúario é o root da maquina, qual usuario está conectando ao shell?

Comment: o usuário michael

Comment: Eu teria que saber em que maquina está, é um servidor dedicado ou compartilhado Aonde te deram acesso ao shell? Além desse usúario michael com certeza existe o root um super usuário. Entra em contato com o suporte do servidor e solicita a senha de acesso.

Comment: Está tudo localmente na minha máquina. Eu sou o root!